# Static Employee number, file handling issue

Tags: java, sequence

I am having a problem with my Employee number static variable with file handling. When I create a new Employee I automatically get the next number in sequence. But when I restart the program and try to create a new Employee the employee number reverts back to 1.

Is there any method that anyone might suggest to read the previous employee and continue numbering from there?

Thank you in advance any any help!! :)

```
     @SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable
{   
    private Date dateOfBirth; 
    private Date startDate;
    private double salary;
    private int employeeNumber;
    private static int nextEmployeeNumber = 1;  

    private final double MAX_SALARY = 70000;
    private final double INCREMENT = 250;


    public Employee()
    {
        super();
        dateOfBirth = new Date();
        startDate = new Date();
        salary = 0.0;
        employeeNumber = nextEmployeeNumber++;
    }



    public Employee(String title, String firstName, String surname, String     phoneNumber, 
                int day, int month, int year, int sD, int sM, int sY, double     salary)
    {
        super(title, firstName, surname, phoneNumber);
        this.dateOfBirth = new Date(day, month, year);
        this.startDate = new Date(sD, sM, sY);
        this.employeeNumber = employeeNumber++;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    //Overrides the toString methods, providing its own implementation
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return(super.toString() + "\nEmployee Number: " + employeeNumber +     "\nEmployee Salary: " + salary + 
                              "\nEmployee DOB: " + dateOfBirth + "\nEmployee     Start Date: " + startDate);
    }


    //Both .equals methods are usable. To save any possible conflicts as might occur 
    //in a larger system, I have set the equals method to call back to the Object class
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
    {
        Employee other = (Employee) otherObject;
        if (otherObject == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if(getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
        {   
            return false;
        }

        if(super.name.equals(otherObject)&&
          (employeeNumber == other.employeeNumber)&&
          (dateOfBirth == other.dateOfBirth)&&
          (startDate == other.startDate)&&
          (salary == other.salary));
        {
           return true;
        }
    }

    int quit = 0;
    public void read()
    {   
        Scanner kbInt = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner kbString = new Scanner(System.in);



        System.out.print("\n\nEmployee Title: "); 
        name.title = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee First Name: "); 
        name.firstName = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Surname: "); 
        name.surname = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee DOB Day: "); 
        dateOfBirth.day = kbInt.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee DOB Month: "); 
        dateOfBirth.month = kbInt.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee DOB Year: "); 
        dateOfBirth.year = kbInt.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Phone Number: "); 
        phoneNumber = kbString.nextLine();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Start Day: "); 
        startDate.day = kbString.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Start Month: "); 
        startDate.month = kbString.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Start Year: "); 
        startDate.year = kbString.nextInt();

        System.out.print("\nEmployee Salary: "); 
        salary = kbInt.nextDouble();
    }



    //Getters & Setters of DOB, start date, employee number & salary
    public Date getDateOfBirth() 
    {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) 
    {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public Date getstartDate() 
    {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) 
    {
         this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;

    }

    public int getEmployeeNumber() 
    {
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    public double getSalary() 
    {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        this.salary = salary;
        if(salary < 0 || salary > 70000)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Enter Valid Salary");
    }

    public void incrementSalary()
    {
        if(salary + INCREMENT <= MAX_SALARY)
            salary += INCREMENT;
        else
            salary = MAX_SALARY;
    }       
 }


     import java.util.*;
           import java.io.*;
           import java.nio.file.*;

           /**
            * Class B.Sc. CSDF
            * Instructor Maria Boyle
            * Description: EmployeeMenu class for Hotel application
            * Date: 01/11/2015
            * @author Mark Melling
            * @version 1.0
            */

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            //   This class contains an ArrayList, and the methods for modifying  //
            //   the ArrayList as required, as well as the methods for serializing//
            //   and deserializing the ArrayList                                  //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

           @SuppressWarnings("serial")
           public class EmployeeFileHandler_1 implements Serializable
           {
            //Declare ArrayList called employees - for storing a list of Employees
            private ArrayList<Employee> employees;
            private Scanner keyIn = new Scanner(System.in);

            public EmployeeFileHandler_1()              // Default Constructor
            {
                employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();  // Construct Employee ArrayList
            }


            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Method Name : add()                              //
            // Return Type : void                               //
            // Parameters : None                                //
            // Purpose: Reads one Employee record from the user //
            //        and adds it to the ArrayList employeeList //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

            public void add()
            {
                Employee employee = new Employee();         // Create a Employee object

                employee.read();                            // Read its details 
                employees.add(employee);                    // Add it to the employeeList
            }

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Method Name : list()                             //
            // Return Type : void                               //
            // Parameters : None                                //
            // Purpose: Loops around the ArrayList employeeList //
            //          and prints to screen employee details   //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            public void list() 
            {
                for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
                {
                    System.out.println(currentEmployee);        
                }       
            }

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Method Name: view()                              //
            // Return Type: void                                //
            // Parameters:  None                                //
            // Purpose:     View Employee record from the       //
            //              ArrayList employeeList              //
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////  

            public void view() 
            {
                //Read the number of the Employee to be viewed
                System.out.println("\nEnter Employee Number:");
                int employeeToView = keyIn.nextInt();

                //Read every Employee object in videos
                for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
                {
                    // If it's number equals the number of the Employee to view
                    if(currentEmployee.getEmployeeNumber() == employeeToView)
                    {
                        //Display Employee
                        System.out.println(currentEmployee);
                        break;
                    }
                }   
            }

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Method Name: delete()                              //
            // Return Type: void                                  //
            // Parameters:  None                                  //
            // Purpose:     Reads Employee record from the        //
            //              ArrayList employeeList & deletes user //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            public void delete()
            {
                //Read the number of the video to be deleted from the user
                System.out.println("Enter Number of Employee To Delete");
                int employeeToDelete = keyIn.nextInt();

                //for every Video object in videos
                for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
                {
                    //if it's number equals the number of the Video to view
                    if(currentEmployee.getEmployeeNumber() == employeeToDelete)
                    {
                        //display it
                        System.out.println(currentEmployee);

                        //Remove it from videos
                        employees.remove(currentEmployee);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }


            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Method Name: delete()                              //
            // Return Type: void                                  //
            // Parameters:  None                                  //
            // Purpose:     Reads Employee record from the        //
            //              ArrayList employeeList & edits user   //
            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            public void edit()
            {
                //Read the number of the employee to be edited from the user
                System.out.println("Enter number of Employee to edit");
                int employeeToEdit = keyIn.nextInt();

                //for every Employee object in employees
                for(Employee currentEmployee : employees)
                {
                    //if it's number equals the number of the employee to view
                    if(currentEmployee.getEmployeeNumber() == employeeToEdit)
                    {
                        //Display employee
                        System.out.println(currentEmployee);

                        //get it's index
                        int index = employees.indexOf(currentEmployee);

                        //read in a new employee
                        currentEmployee.read();

                        //reset the object in employees
                        employees.set(index, currentEmployee);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Method Name : writeRecordsToFile()                //
            // Return Type : void                                //
            // Parameters : None                                 //
            // Purpose: Writes the ArrayList employees to the    //
            //          file employees.bin before closing it     //
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 

            public void writeRecordsToFile()
            {
                if(employees instanceof Serializable)
                try
                {
                    // Serialize the ArrayList...
                    FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream("employees.bin");

                    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fileStream);

                    os.writeObject(employees);

                    os.close();
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException fNFE)
                {
                    System.out.println("Cannot create file to store employees.");
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Input Output Error" + e.getMessage());
                }
            }   

            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // Method Name: readRecordsToFile()                     //
            // Return Type: void                                    //
            // Parameters:  None                                    //
            // Purpose:     Reads the ArrayList employees from the  //
            //              file employees.bin, uses the Path.get   //
            //              method to test whether the path to the  //
            //              file exists & adds error handling.      //          
            //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public void readRecordsFromFile()
            {
                if(employees instanceof Serializable)
                try
                {
                    final String FILENAME = "employees.bin";
                    Path p = Paths.get(FILENAME);

                    if(Files.exists(p))
                    {
                        //Creates Object
                        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(p.toString());
                        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);

                        Object o = is.readObject();             //READ an Object from the file
                        if(o instanceof ArrayList)              //IF Object is an ArrayList
                        employees = (ArrayList<Employee>)o;     //ASSIGN Object to employees
                        is.close(); 
                    }
                    else    
                    {
                        System.out.println("File "+p.getFileName() + "Doesnt exist");
                    }       
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException fNFE)
                {
                    System.out.println("File not found " + fNFE.getMessage());
                }
                catch(IOException iOE)
                {
                    System.out.println("Input output error " + iOE.getMessage());
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to serialise/persist your data for this. This can either be done by writing your data to a file, use or database or other methods.

Then you can read your data from the database/file to retrieve all persisted entries and find out the next employee number.

** edit **
you edited my answer instead of posting it

Comment: Hi..sorry about that! I am still getting used to the format of this site. I have added my file handler class to the post. I'm still a little confused as where I go from here.

Comment: @Mark For simple persistence between program runs take a look at the [Java Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/overview.html).